# How to send an image to php through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am getting an image from file with javascript, then I am attempting to send the image to a PHP script for processing, but I am unable to decipher it inside the php file

here is my JavaScript code.

```
var image_file;

function getPhoto(){

    var file = document.getElementById('ad_photo');
    var image = document.getElementById('ad_photo_upload');
    var fReader = new FileReader();
    fReader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
    image_file = file.files[0];
    fReader.onloadend = function(event){

        image.src = event.target.result; 

    }   

}

function update_profile(){

    var file = document.getElementById('ad_photo_upload');
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', image_file);

    var url = "profile/update/";

    HTTP.open("POST", url, true);
    HTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    HTTP.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(HTTP.readyState == 4 && HTTP.status == 200){

            document.getElementById("df").innerHTML = HTTP.responseText;

        }
    }
    HTTP.send(data);

}
```

PHP

```
public function update(){

    var_dump($_POST);

}
```

Var_dump result

```
array (size=657)
  '------WebKitFormBoundary67r2AtAPnklDtBm5
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name' => string '"file"; filename="1420338105027.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

�����JFIF���������C�




���C        

�����"��������������    
�������}�!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�    
%' (length=342)
  ''()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������' => string '��i�q' (length=5)
  '�#��7�u]�ϛ����1D��~���' => string 'vo����ǃ,|/k�I����Oo�L����_' (length=30)
  '����N�' => string '���}z����K�j��3�ى�M5�Z��.k����j{{��_to��e' (length=47)
  '�j�ZW���FzS�y���-����9_fHߝ:ӢVy1]������O���um;K�˴k��t������ڎ���W��V�KC' => string '���߻��:��������Z�N��>�<'�6�m���>   ����l<?��_�̰��Rl���j���>���p�����L�s{�������."��iWKp���9-|ϻ�����R�q'��' (length=117)
  '�c��
_X�Z��u��cʻ>O�eV6�F���U��n�r�#����Wf�(<�/�F�' => string '��4'��S���ce��]���ޯ���@    f������' (length=35)
  '������6�n�R����2�t�����_�' => string 'C��s�O���?ܪ�}̰ȋ���R|��%6�P��'�ZI���%]�lHβE�I��M�>�����X�� ���k�����,��"�HK�Ѧ�۵Ҕ�ҿ�>D������];؇mͭ?��͝��vr[%㬲�۱�T���jm�k�ɳ;֫G��R]��g�_?�?
��n������?ܩ�g"�RV4.m_d
����yޒ6Y�7�����=����i' (length=213)
  '�Υ��|��$>W�o˧�O��{_#d�]�y�Z�gZ�Լ��H�W��?��' => string '��Q����V:̾C��Α�% 1������ڰ�Ku�߅����9��/����}��.[��c�?��3yM"�����UYb�sI�?��ܬ�'��A��:����q �O�t~�_�Q}��G�jv�~��DV�^�t���)�]!�'��]��K��=��}u�]����O�ޮ���J���;���έ�]ԺM��_����.��|�F駂H�o��r��O�㕟Sr�(yk!����${$������-*嵒�?io���?۫����3�5�����#����{�qc-��$�����瑧��o�B���7�����O���x���������_t_�� :׈<5�4��H��;���q�})��rvGc�~�:��Z|H�-'����|��w�_<��~O�M����<"�_���ۍ
�' (length=408)
  '�6ZI�|��<Wŗ�f�' => string '�e7-�觻 ��_���YVO���/�6U�x%����{J����f�"�����ε�g�i�q��G��y��kA�< ��c�A�[���_��*���s$mq'��' (length=95)
  '��(��N�<0���U��X�lu6�' => string 'T7�)�|���' (length=9)
  'G��K^^x��O�4�����I�e�|�ZV�վw�V�d��' => string '�k���|/Ο����4wR���;��v����G���G�?����,�>�թ����G�U��Z϶4�*�����h������eZ/2H[�Tsg��\�:mk@��� i:�����B���E�h��m��\�' (length=121)
  ''�����#������' => string '�k�?�?��Rmt�ٳ�V/�<�d�����Q�������n�`����,' (length=44)
  '����p�r�V��$��' => string '�ߪ���"��?ۤx� ��"��#� ���Pi��Y�y�������S���_�O�(�Fmb���4�'�_��C7�%�~G����� i��
�e�'�fM���~�n?x�������� ��`��=����r���}Rx�_����-*R�;��>M�r�����aky�\@�ď��}2fO>8c�f�s@��n#���D?�[���������' (length=200)
  '�|]' => string '�#�oH?���vm�' (length=13)
  '���°I��}�' => string '��7�s�����,�dm��ˑ�
ڿ��6H��w�M�F�O/��ۿ�ښ�_��'���������|t�/rm�8����}��}��������Y]�/ܭ�Kvx�h�5�����H������?�_�g���w��'����nBcV5�㍤����T 
��Zɲ����W��J��o�i��
�>t\���rϾ�*�>o�o⥂�I�.�ɿ}Mo� ���w�����#9����u�.%
�o�"�U��i��g��"�/�a'�Z���o�'h^!�?���"�F��G�w:��잴�IH\��%yx�ű(Xe~�z��~W[tލ��I%>=�' (length=309)
  'o/���
Ȱ|�~�����پ��n#j�Qy�cV�䊪��l�'�Q�b�G�H�g�?��r�d�g���*9��<�,������;�x�?٥�_���_*��\t' => string 'R��M�K��W�����' (length=15)
  '������?�_öw?�ֿ��kc���7��m�Y�<��' => string '���I�� �zd����GĠ�<�uX�H��6I�9⾒��e= �wïx��Ŷ:ĺ�Q��v����' (length=64)
  '�w�y���' => string 'Ho�A]��/�Z�ōvM'ñ�5�P����yI�}ꆓ%��|F�U����mw�����Ԭ��Ug�?��m����E�weM�[�T,۩��ur$c��O�r��I�gݠ��Kjc�h��O�"fԲ6��Q�����m=b��������H��g�����~_�6�]�������ɫd�ꘉ��.�����r��l��W�=cS}kR���4��v��O����K��h�����{n�Q�SR��Ӥg��w�����nfG���c1����:�����FU�kyJ��t�I�T2/�57���zb }����h�5L_1d� ���eM�_���M-��-���%E�Z��Ꙋm��W���ٲ���n�PȾSӣ���U�ۻ4j�����*���r�o����1doߢ����m\VK���k�5v����s=;V��Ty<�����KH�O-w�*�W���}��|?�΢��;����T�Xvv?�����\B�l�\����B���v������?�[7��m>�Eu �' (length=501)
  'ӹ>D�
���7B����k�(��żV�*y�' => string 'n��-�m�7��tN�$V���UU�ԋ*�
��!a�$�|�j[{]��m'����"e��䦧�[��,_%%mخ������ė^��0�S��a@��g�\\�U��窺v�����s?�3�����F��MK
���7Z�F�G��m̿v����̌�7}Jy�5����E���c�ຂ� E�Py�����\ �����ur�/��:��U�ui��wֺ\wS��v���O�t��nw����eۧ�>z�>j����������������3T���\O���3�����T���(ɱ��������d��R�9��ų�W�[��M����?���U%�cO��   ����~c����t�M�/���:�C$��/�����U�k�m�܍���X���j�2Әo<�ꮛ��j0_嫐E�O2�����Z�z�,X��:������{7�J�c��[K��#�o��Y��}�n�����ޢy[����w��,G6ǞW�����ul࡭�cؿh�� �g���
m5 -�v�q/��{�'... (length=528)
  '�VHg?}��bHr����_��%��d�˩��vU�I�_�$��e_�����/g�~���T��>�s�|�R��ig��h��΋���k%ݾ��Kuy��' => string '�Ŀ��/�F���]���Ǔ6���J��B����>ߓ��%ơsu���GD���Y���[M� ��\�O~�d����{�Q|�q�j%����%�;G���-\ѫ��#��}ƨc'��Ш�����۽
"y[a�c��~��zyr��-65��o�j�]]b�d��$����=��ʮ�1M���Ю�`�Z��-dk����UH��#�j�D�7��W%�/6d��j�@�9�ύ6���
���y?�����\���,��Y���Z6:��<q��.��u�ȏ��Sj�]���Oc�G���e������.��"�>�"���rI4��O��-���u.6d��<p~���l��(Ԥ}9,����g��x6��Z��涛��>F���Xd����[�m��#��n��QZ�u}�U���q�v�|Ug�iV:a�d�]S}��oM[�.=���%̈́�M���|�
��_��/�\��U��x�����kH;��%G�
� 8 b��g��f����qW�N݁#sƟu�:��N�'�l'... (length=647)
  '��x��8��5?�V-�yc�o����v����' => string '£o��g�~*��~*�|A��u-������1IZ� 5��O4~BUɼ��' (length=45)
  'O?w���__�W��?jZ�~\]M�ed,r��yq����' => string 'A�����������"�U���.����{ԣ�
����Þ#�7R�n���d�e]�FW �/��t����Ȼy��7�'�G��{_�AIwϿ{���j���W�Zg����/�Pi���o5��ڭ:u�����B�M���H�>��>_Z��K����>��r�m�r���d�I�DO���I!���!�w��Sx~�,�V�������>��0��3��Tt�حqR�����/���z#���8�`�������S��m̐��Ǘ����z����V
< ����Px�]rѭ��d۾��x��|��n����m�����t��U������~_�vt��2���G4�����#;/�H��)���^��_T��m������ �ㅚ�F_��b�(��=�$���n�)7`)��ɻ�P����J$�X��jHc��IM �)۴���Վ�6�=�6��\>ī�m���af�]�J��<��ܧk�7�#�������$_r����v�ҍL�n�Qմ�����>�?2�/��Ƭ������'... (length=765)
  '˹���
A��UЭm�Ac�$�lV�㱓{ڳv8�(d{o�o���' => string '��[ZH�G��u�8'�$�y=D���;I' (length=26)
  ' ��:s7�'�H��*���' => string '1�Z/���@
�m���}�!f����b7ɾJ�>!|-�~A��j^F�^�n��߲6�\���i����N�,��D����~G����_\��?���xWŶ�$�����m�b����rv��=Ɵ%��9$�ꯜ���T��^�.���Qգ��y�z���Cx���R��_e�_��o�K�u�1��%����������=�]'X<�1�ﺟ�>A�C�����VW����\6  6����w����t�-�K{��仓���.4��[(5-�M>_�;�:|������������r��f����Ɍ��6����e�Oku�\'�������Ӷ�$�E����jt ��]7��r:�J�|"��y�G�z������ܧ��Oi,��ˤI�� ���'�<[���_q��~N�'߽��ߥy��p}���d�����$�b��v�q��W�|�:��[�>�Z����n�����/��漶��o.<�hy]�$u�O�|K����G�<5=���y�:7϶�V"R����O�'... (length=831)
  '��N�����~J����_:Yy��l���߻�f�ח�f�yq7�T4Rο��*Z�%rK��$�~zl,����P��#�c�NY���۱�Ww,\<Lv���
Ϛ��M�WO�@���S��O_O�X7sx��?���"Ԋ�#�' => string '�}V���w-j��Z�Ct�w;��lo��mq%����ʋP�KX��7�/�R��1���C[�����'� ' (length=66)
  '_���4��G��kzR�g-VzO�~ǫ|%���լb���m��y�_�ܹ܉�U孵ko��' => string '���O��' (length=6)
  '��_84�}�SN{�����*E�oݨcC��T�_K���T6�;��*|�ϗ���C_̟2��b�v���' => string '�,V�\Qk
m�Cw2ݼ�_v�y�鵶���o�������-B�w���~��]�c��?���Ѯ���d��-���Q��gޮ��������
/X����r��B���z��nL]�S%��ި�wܮ���O��~����7���q,�n�}�:���p�VMՔ���؋`o����Zu���P]I]�]���V,���jkYb�$�#���J��I��I�_]�
�Z��� ��*��3����۷mjr��2�R�nE�3I��/�,���UԮ��}�f��_xW��O���L��RTY|��G�Yz�s��V�ֳ��������4e���|B׾(k��x���
JT��w��V�)Β���n��[����y�����;�Q�#��T��{��U�v�~Y#��ָ��B�~_���fe�[��R���/���7t��D��
�#y{(ޡ~�)������F��Fo��M����۽���|��/�f��#���٭-?V�Ӡ�c����M���8��ȿ'������3��ٟ¾����i>4'... (length=670)
  '�����_1��f�:���p��C�' => string '����- ����K]>��X��Z-�������������4g-�4]�W�d��{�_�a��֢Vh�d�wH���w�{F������'�����<5kv���j�=�ؐ~�V������I|og�|7P@������?º
�������إD�����
����k#���' (length=157)
  '������j���j��?����խr��Iԧ��7ۦݒR33ReI$X�؏�' => string '6
���>�kR�dYN,n~o/�߳���H�O��o��������m�T�xZ������f�-��h�t�Oگ��͊y?�����CB����AqO��x��r�����w_Ɖ����kx�Q��Ԯ��w��l��]{V]�N>6K\�X�RQ*,�T���������PЭ�ܞ^���J�̱y�������Go^��<��f���6WZ���ܐ=���~��LZI�' (length=219)
  '����' => string '�~�X��!?�\�z�dV"y��r���>t���!����ݣ�n��?�>jܻ�� �Ѵt�-�' (length=56)
  'ɼ�si�gc'����o�\���q�f<2Koi�?�i���DV������G�_mo%{K���t�$�zޥ-��io�H�����?�JSN:�F
�>��_X}�c�o��' => string 'WO����ۏ9,c�
��' (length=17)
  '�7�X��2�' => string '�m�7�-bc'���G��E�y�<Ƨ�IU�i�V����Dm�_/g�P�AS������Z�� ��D��Z|�f4�O�R\6.�%    �B�Q��|���d�,H��߫e[��oɷ��y�ۈ�_ᮡ��k�:��
' (length=129)
  '�໽j���;�_-�Gu�޹8{���ܟ��' => string '���|���՛����#������IV�Y��8?���g���M�Y�0h_��d�' (length=52)
  'X��<����k���WIյ{H�}?N��' => string 'J��ld�_�'��l���5Z�<=w�Az��=�?�{���P�t'�C���M�ޕ�i����~��R��}�D���r�Pq%̉���%P��;����n�7��^�#�`��7S����$�uC�h3��k}��l�����^��c�v>*��N��k:tv������}A���^]�j��7�n]������{�_��*���6>��������?�$��}>�����w���uZ������\i6Gi����}>�.�y*k���e��=�l�$��/,���1gH-%���u�8^�S([���}�4yY����w�|O#y3��m���Y>F�6T�sy������������4�JH�K{���?�U��������>?|2�<��F�����Ͼ����k��9�?�������׸��' (length=394)
  '�^��dzN�a$?���o��7tӏ2�����/�,�I�-~G����c\Ki���t߳�V�����'���' => string '��i�J�~}����>�<���UxU���d�C�yqɱ�X`������:Sݟ{GN��H���z��VTEX�n���%�޶��;�����
�x�\��t}�jwR��}
�G��>��y�Of���-4RI����ח'�>��]/��t��O���-�]�������W9$���5�����=�1P�ޛ�4K������f�|��`-w#I,pE��=����כm3�O�$�����w������-c��m��������j�-lg�?wn�����ܥȆ����$�{K���ح?�aw��èI$zl�lw����d��v�{n��Yqm��~GJ.�Cw/��-6�\����y�����}�ozm����}��d���;��v�#���Zl���D�yq<?��*��w2����Siv�O}��y7��T2I��<��쑲��>w��>�8��u_�Q>���I�g��~����g����7�W����cJ�K;����?������,I$����M(m߻���<��H�_�@����S'... (length=853)
  '�)~��W���yq����ʖ�:\"����Y��:ɕ�S�h����߹���d��{>M�����i$�>Jr�K���ʞ���m�kK��,k*m���' => string 'Kp�����V�O��oM����ڼ��O�g�Rp�S� �$��I���{���t�Đ-�˽}.��ɭ��go>�=7��j;�Gr�Ѵ_7��:h��?��\X��r O�_g��M�r��Yj��V�rI�O���Qj����E��F���Zo�>�Uu�ʏ��r��nF˷�q��ḻI~�������o���UG�?�I�V:"0���R7̟5[�Og������PI��*��;2������"m_�V-���#H��*6�%��X�-d�o���3I���r��o���`ף�7�[�Zo������nn<��ܮ�x'��w�Q�'�᫋���y�7ݪ�y�\w8���
������
���7着�' (length=351)
  'c�,j���u���b�̈́�9��
��KO����f�e�^�'�Rh�#p�aK���W��������8�X��_��<oz�g��Zf����R�j��թ�}���}�h���GLƻ�U�ڞд_�}�b�����VƗ����_�,��j��̠��}v�' => string '��=C��t{(/����.�' (length=17)
  '�0���e��_���w�k�(��#X�Z��4�' => string 's����)����V��
��5' (length=17)
  '�/'�����' => string 'm���e��{�-���JFvh�������c����m܅cf޻�Z�����q���=� ������������驯�.�~ѧ���U��s���E�������H���'��ެɫ��i�����r�g��`~JU�
 .����r���2��
I5f�MK��U�K��}.����b�߲���6n���r��k��W���Q�cLk� ����%��� �M��÷�����\������� ���i�����V�i�����D�?{��}��^�%�@#f�x�~_����5�A�8�Y�6{������ؕ�����}��  ~���^iO�Ca�|�m��5�`(��svH��Q��|��/�W����ۛ�W��"��[W]�\l��8�
��'�_]~�?����3ŰZirC5�ɾ%��J} ��I?}����?µ�����5(�gF���Aq�U�[a�G'�����Y��j���ޯ"QQ�ڝ�g����$����Z>�n����Zg������U�[�����Go��YGr�'... (length=844)
  '������Ww_j
Z��ڿ�k�����' => string 'j{O����c��7w�U��W�
��'G�H����g����?��Ջw���q�Ի?�?�D���(�V�inI�ȩ�����' (length=76)
  '�u���d�d��ϲ��x_��k�W�ޫ�cĳ��]��Է�_�I��zW_��ˬ�Wz���{��g�>�3U*jE%vU�}���lد^��w��w���/4' => string '7��|[|�#�
���<���߽$��~��;>=�/�>
Լ?�]G�^����?�ڼµZ1Uc��J7>���o<�O��2Aw����⬏����|��/�Ҿ���>3x�o��#P��>բڣ[�Ή�{�����a���Ok�����}.��?J�p�؊�Svimn`�f������#���6��� ������l���I�)~�{>�R"(�����\�H�Z|���4q�������I|���w�����C��٤�.<�����^$����}6;-n�!�4���;w�W,��j�V ?7���)W��$Y#t�*���g����/��r�l�Y|���7��z��w]�����1־���\�_ȽD��[�3S��J{ŒK���g����l�=�M�k' (length=379)
  '�q��' => string 'k�RV7J�T6s����^��Yg�'ܭXt�)'�I��bO�Ջ._3�h���zy����΋W�l��7���uY5���}� ��u�jL�I�D�����V�E��Xk��}��w|���$�K�;�e��_h�M���}��>|�� o���1i�o���r�RMZ�$[��>��ְ4���/��n����Qks�jV3��v�����-����z���5�O$��� ���Ъ��Miu����j�䰹����lu�7�ޫV:T~z^j����������*)Jz�z���4�I��w���܎�߽���4Ղ8�/7�}������6v7� ��oejۼ�#�=����[���q�' (length=347)
  '�' => string 'f�
ե�� "���[��|��]�j����f��8�C.���NNk����u'��}ڷ%̺n�$�' (length=64)
  '�V��$�31��y����U
����g��>�_�O�����,��g{O�f_��W���������z�J�iܯ,�֑n���' => string '?�7���x�������oB��]���řr����#���y#���>�Y�O�Y?s�P�zI�Y��_�W}���m'p(�#J���fښ�6��S�y�'��o��?�'�*8dd��լ�]ܖ7ouv���:�h�'�?3{�-:���/�'ɻ�z|�yl�����O,f��{o��g�|���)d��F��_��O�)4ي\�kS������q*���%���?�U����}�$2o�DY����I���̺ot��?���F1�������r!�=�~zr���j����g�Eҵ��,c�$�����t�05�3�}Oŷ�X����7�� 9��M�KV����[����c�xR�����@����5qu/�%��ow�������k���o��G����ߕ<�2M��䎜��ni K�7�i���}}i��ik6�������2#��(��<߹]ǁ�U���^���۸������}����X>9�,u���M��]�����~��'�����W��g���i�{k�{�XͺA$"�h?���E�'... (length=801)
  '��4F�,K�I>�Wn��C_������o�?�Y�j��7H��_w�����]��l��yկ_{��O�\���_<�{g�' => string 'bd6�n��ٲ�_m�@�����[A�$_�|�����O��Ϟ�WGs<�/�Z[y<����M�Y��ˏb5I�ğz�� �,��ǳ��;�=E-��I�����o�����7����ZZm���i�Z��w��' (length=129)
  'O�(4���<;���^kAt�_�q����Y�m�����??m5�j�2"/��Ik�[�' => string 'W1\���~t�M�oz���>z�sn�I�o�����������Ԭv}���' (length=44)
  'k�og����|�g�՜�����o�`x���' => string ' 8�R�|��,���,�y~w�-�e���?1�%�/�M�od�2�c%�kd�' (length=47)
  '���U��J��59u��P��%�d����d5�6|1��W�7�' => string '������|��r�N�������>T���I�yO�,�WT�
�4�E�����t}���q��:��,I��_������t��K�_�t_G����t�w���=G�s�,���' (length=107)
  '�-�~L��' => string 's��N-'��?y��Xhz\m���f���ڭ���^�w��/�wk3B��    ��Y�:��%�w�����?��K��7�f���_�'��p��/������S�zM����-��ibW���)#e�Kۉu9ck���T���������X��"��Smݒ8���W���u�'�J�)�h����z�X�F�̒;�[�Y��r�>�|yҿ���WKmw��� �k  ?� w�
�?����\դ�<��    "[���WJ���5tmmGO���X��D��U�)3��qҧ��e�Y<Ǟ�[6�1��e������=W��m�9�� p7��uDO���u���w��]��Y�}�$�g�w����V�ol���I�Zd2\�2yq��Y������Z�b�W�
�:�ٺ��X%�8����y����~d�o���=���k�n���r�Աoo��uW�"��������P�Y?��8�����O[�d�Z�R����L!K�Q{
 �ll��q�r;���'���U�n�}:G������|�<{_mz��}��O'... (length=1488)
```

How would I amend this code, so that I am able to decipher the data as an image on the php side.

Comment: So if the problem is server-side do you not think it would be a good idea to display your PHP source code?

Comment: What do you mean by 'decipher the data as an image'? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: At the moment I am just using var_dump($_POST); which throws me this:array (size=657)
  '------WebKitFormBoundary67r2AtAPnklDtBm5
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name' => string '"file"; filename="1420338105027.jpg"

Comment: I want to send the image to php so that I can store it as a blob in my database. Plus that var_dump also throws a ton of encrypted jibberish

Comment: Rather than posting this in the comments section, edit/update your question with the relevant information for others to see at first glance. Confirm your ajax is posting to the php? Display the return of the php? information like this can speed up the process of help.

Comment: I have amended my post

Comment: Does anyone have a clue how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm still working out what it is you're trying to accomplish. So once the image is sent to your php, you want to what? Save the image to a directory and save the image name/path to your database?

Comment: yes, or just save the image directly as BLOB. Either way is fine, I just want to know how I can send the image to the PHP properly.

Comment: just remove this line, and i think it should work:     HTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: because it SHOULD be something like HTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary67r2AtAPnklDtBm5");

Comment: but XMLHttpRequest.send(FormData) will do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line, and i think it should work:

```
HTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

because the correct header would be something like

```
HTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary67r2AtAPnklDtBm5");
```

but XMLHttpRequest.send(FormData) will set that for you automatically.
when you overwrite content-type here, with the wrong value, it makes PHP parse the $_POST wrong, and you get this useless/wrongly parsed data in $_POST :p